# JVM (embarrasingly) parallel processing libraries/tools

Tags: java, clojure, parallel-processing, jvm, embarrassingly-parallel

I am looking for something that will make it easy to run (correctly coded) embarrassingly parallel JVM code on a cluster (so that I can use Clojure + Incanter).

I have used Parallel Python in the past to do this. We have a new PBS cluster and our admin will soon set up IPython nodes that use PBS as the backend. Both of these systems make it almost a no-brainer to run certain types of code in a cluster.

I made the mistake of using Hadoop in the past (Hadoop is just not suited to the kind of data that I use) - the latency made even small runs execute for 1-2 minutes.

Is JPPF or Gridgain better for what I need? Does anyone here have any experience with either? Is there anything else you can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure is reported to work on [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/), subject to some patching.

Answer (score 3):

Check out cascalog - http://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Skandium](http://skandium.niclabs.cl/)

Edit :

Above link is no more live, so adding github link

https://github.com/mleyton/Skandium

Comment: Looks promising, but GPL is a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at [Skandium](http://skandium.niclabs.cl), alternative licenses to GPL can be negotiated with the developers upon request.